# How to load external Javascript file in MVC 5 _Layout Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to call external js file in mvc 5 _layout page, i have done a few researches on google, but no success, below is my code in the _Layout Head section:

```
<!-- start: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="~/assets/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/assets/plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/plugins/jQuery-lib/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/jQuery-lib/2.0.3/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/iCheck/jquery.icheck.min.js")"></script>

    <!-- end: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            Main.init();
            Index.init();
        });
    </script>

    @RenderSection("JavaScript", required : false)
    @RenderSection("CSS", required : false)
```

Then at the bottom of the _Layout page i have this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/assets/plugins")
@RenderSection("Scripts", required : false)
```

In the View, i have this:

```
@section JavaScript
{

<!-- start: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/jquery.sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/js/index.js")">

</script>
<!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
}
```

Please i will appreciate i someone could assist in suggesting what to do. thanks

Comment: u can use  requirejs for more concretae app with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

to before its dependencies

i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js")"></script>
```

requires JQuery.js

but you load it after. So moving the include of JQuery above the script which required it, will fix that issue.

Please apply this to all scripts and their dependencies

Comment: Please do i need to register the all my js file and path in bundle file before doing this?

Comment: Thanks so much, that resolves the issue, i spent many days trying to figure out the issue, thanks once again for saving my time.

Comment: @UwakMfon NP, I could see that was the problem, just wish i had more energy to write/explain it  better, glad you read it..., and got what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in normal HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://link-to-external-javascript-file.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not an absolute link, i have tried similar way to reference the relative link, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.